# How to convert Razor Page to String in Controller

Tags: razor, controller

Just want to ask on how to convert the whole Razor page(.cshtml) into string in Controller.

i have a created an Action Template below:

```
public ActionResult Template()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

and in the page it shows below:

```
<div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width: 940px">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="/Content/assets/img/logo.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="dbox">
        <label class="clabel">Test1 # </label>          <span>: Value1</span><br>
        <label class="clabel">Test2 </label>                <span>: Value2</span><br>
        <label class="clabel">Test2 </label>            <span>: Value3</span><br>
        <label class="clabel">Test3 : </label>          <span>: Value4</span><br>
        <label class="clabel">Test4 </label>            <span>: Value5</span><br>
        <label class="clabel">Test5 Change </label>     <span>: Value6</span><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

how do i convert that into string?

Comment: First off, why would you need something like that? And if, why dont you just use `StreamReader` to read the cshtml file?

Comment: how can i do that, can you give me an example?